# MQTT broker на роутере

Tags: amazon, esp8266, mqtt

Есть некоторое количество устройств на базе *ESP8266*, которые нужно подружить с сервисами амазона посредством протокола MQTT. 
Роутер хочу использовать *Xiaomi Mi WiFi Router 3G*, опционально с прошивкой от Padavan.

Возможно ли установить на вышеуказанный роутер MQTT broker по типу Mosquitto?
Кто-то так уже делал?

Comment: Не подскажите подробней, как делали? Второй день бьюсь, не запускается.

Comment: Вот, если еще актуально, ссылочка на репу падавана, там описано, как ставить пакеты на энтверь https://bitbucket.org/padavan/rt-n56u/wiki/RU/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20Entware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xiaomi Mi WiFi Router с прошивкой от **Padavan** поддерживает пакеты **Entware**

Вот пакет **Entware Mosquitto MQTT broker** 
https://github.com/Entware-ng/entware-packages/tree/master/net/mosquitto

Установка на Mi Mini прошла успешно.
Вот лог запуска:

```
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: mosquitto version 1.4.14 starting
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Config loaded from /opt/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
Feb  4 06:46:55 mosquitto[527]: New connection from 192.168.1.65 on port 1884
```

[image: Скриншот системного журнала]

Скриншот:
https://yadi.sk/i/YUupADzt3S53fD

Comment: Ау вас есть возможность попробовать?

Comment: У меня прошивка Padavan стоит на роутере Xiaomi Mi Mini.
Если получится настроить, могу написать. 
Поиск в инете результатов не дал. Нашел только этот вопрос.
Неужели никто еще кроме меня этого не собрался сделать?)

Comment: @0xdb
Установка прошла успешно.
Вот лог запуска:

Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: mosquitto version 1.4.14 starting
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Config loaded from /opt/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
Feb  4 06:46:50 mosquitto[527]: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
Feb  4 06:46:55 mosquitto[527]: New connection from 192.168.1.65 on port 1884

Скриншот:
https://yadi.sk/i/YUupADzt3S53fD

Comment: Вот теперь, если кто-то будет искать, найдёт этот вопрос, но уже с ответом.